# What is special about an argument named keys in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm seeing bizarre behavior when I name the argument for a function `keys`.  In the first function (set), I name it keeys, and it works as expected, in the second function (xset) I call it keys and it makes no sense.  I've looked @ the reserved words for javascript and no one mentions keys or set as keywords, however Chromium script console (and SO) colors set (but not keys) as if it is a keyword like var, return, for, true...

Anyway, here is the code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
    function set (keeys) {
        var result = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < keeys.length; i++)
            result[keeys[i]] = true;

        return result;
    }

    function xset (keys) {
      var result = {};

      for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
        result[keys[i]] = true;

      return result;
    }

    var myset1 = set(['a','b','c','d','e']);    
    var myset2 = xset(['a','b','c','d','e']);   

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the debugger output from Chromium.  Breakpoint @ first line of set:

```
> keeys
> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
> keeys.length
> 5
```

Break point @ first line of xset:

```
> keys
> function (object)
    {
        return Object.keys(object);
    }
> keys.length
> 1
```

Comment: If you know the problem, what's the question? `keys` is a shortcut for the `Object.keys` function in Chrome, and possibly other browsers.

Comment: You experienced this issue in Chromium? Which version? I am not able to replicate this issue in any of the popular browsers (I've tested in IE9, IE8, FF4, Ch11, S5, and O11). Demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/R55pE/1/

Comment: It appears like `keys` in the console is a shortcut for `Object.keys` this variable seems to only live in the console.

Comment: The version where this problem occurred is 10.0.648.205.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a bug, since the following works correctly for me (Chrome 11.0.696.60):

```
function bloop(keys) {
    console.log(keys);
}
```

And, after writing this test, ran your code in the console and then in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/egizo4/) (open your console.) Works flawlessly. If you wish, [report it as a bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry) to the Chromium project.

A possible way of tip-toeing around the problem, if you don't want to use `keys`, is to run this at the top of the script:

```
if (keys !== undefined)
    var keys = undefined;
```

And then you can resume normally.

Edit: For those confused, there's a new function added in ES5 (shiny sparkly JavaScript) to the `Object` variable called `keys`. It's called like this:

```
Object.keys({suzy : 4, companion : 'cube', turtle : 'orange'});
//returns ["suzy", "companion", "turtle"]

//or, more abstractly
Object.keys(obj);
```

It returns an array of all the keys in `obj`. Note that `keys` resides in `Object`, NOT `Object.prototype`, so there is no `"hi".keys()` or `obj.keys()`.

Now, for development purposes, the Chromuim team introduced some console-specific functions (like `clear`), which can only be called via the console, and not anywhere else. One of them is a shortcut to `Object.keys`, called `keys`.
Due to perhaps a bug these functions leaked out, causing the problem.

Comment: Glad to see it wasn't something stupid I was doing.  Bug filed http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81183

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly positive, but my best guess is that it has something to do with [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), introduced to Javascript in version 1.8.5.

Note, also, that javascript arrays are really just javascript ***objects*** which is going to further compound the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Very curious, on Chromium 13.0.751.0 I see the following

```
> keys
bound: function (object)
    {
        return Object.keys(object);
    }
> window.keys
undefined
> (1).keys
undefined
> "asd".keys
undefined
> {}.keys
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
> [].keys ()
TypeError: Object  has no method 'keys'
```

Can anyone make any sense out of this?

Comment: It's not a variable, just like `window.clear` isn't a function but you can use `clear()` to clean the console. It's a console-specific function. How it leaks out I have no idea. Also, it's not `{}.keys`, since `keys` isn't in `Object.prototype`, it's in `Object.keys`.